# Angle Bisectors of triangles.

Tags: geometry

I was working on a geometry problem relating to the angle bisectors of triangles :

> In triangle $\Delta ~ABC$, $~∠A=40°,~ ∠B=20°,~$ and $~AB − BC = 4~$. Find the length of angle bisector from $~∠C~$.

I was able to figure out a majority of the angle measures, but I was unable to utilize the information about the side lengths to find the angle bisector.

Does anyone what method I have to use to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Let the angle bisector intersects with $|AB|$ on $D$ and take a point, $E$ on $|AB|$ such that $\angle{ECB}=80^{\circ}$ $\,$ Then, $\,$  $|BE|=|BC|$,$\,$ $\,$   $|AE|=4$ $\,$ $\angle{ECA}=40^{\circ}$  $\,$  which gives us $|EC|=4$. Also $\angle{ECD}=20^{\circ}$, $\angle{DEC}=80^{\circ}$ $\,$ and$\,$  $\angle{EDC}=80^{\circ}$ $\,$ Thus, $|CD|=|EC|=4$

Answer (score 1):

Second solution by using sine rule: Let the angle bisector intersects with |AB| on D

$$\dfrac{\sin{C}}{\sin{A}}=\dfrac{\sin{120^{\circ}}}{\sin{40^{\circ}}}=\dfrac{\sin({40^{\circ}}+{80^{\circ}})}{\sin{40^{\circ}}}=\cos80^{\circ}+2\cos^240^{\circ}=1+2\cos80^{\circ}=\dfrac{x+4}{x}=1+\dfrac{4}{x}$$

$$\\$$
Thus, $$\dfrac{4}{x}=2\cos80$$

$$\\$$

Again by using sine rule on $\triangle{BCD}$ , $$\dfrac{x}{|DC|}=\dfrac{\sin{80^{\circ}}}{\sin{20^{\circ}}}=\dfrac{\sin{80^{\circ}}}{\sin{160^{\circ}}}=\dfrac{1}{2\cos{80^{\circ}}}$$

$$\\$$
Thus, $$|DC|=4$$